# Date/Time formatting

Tags: python, datetime, formatting, twilio

I'm creating a python script that will display busy, no-answer and failed calls for a specific date but I'm stuck on the formatting of the date that's displayed.  The start_time and end_time "variables" from Twilio print something like this:  "Mon, 25 Jul 2016 16:03:53 +0000".  I want to get rid of the day name and the comma since I'm saving the results into a csv file (script_name.py > some_file.csv) and the comma after the day name kind of screws up the csv structure.

In the settings.py file the time_zone variable is set to the right one (America/Chicago) and the USE_TZ variable is set to true.  But anyway the output is still in UTC.

I don't know anything about Python and the things I've tried to parse call.start_time to a datetime have failed . . .  I would know how to do it if it was a given value like start_time = '2016-07-26', but I don't know how to do it when the value comes from for call in client.calls.list . . .

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
from dateutil import tz

# To find these visit https://www.twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "**********************************"
auth_token = "**********************************"

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

for call in client.calls.list(
start_time="2016-07-25",
end_time="2016-07-25",  
status='failed',
):

    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(call.start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code I've provided does simple date and time format.

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
print('The Time is shown below!')
while True:
    time = str(datetime.now())
    time = list(time)
    for i in range(10):
        time.pop(len(time)-1)
    time = ('').join(time)
    time = time.split()
    date = time[0]
    time = time[1]
    print('Time: '+time+', Date: '+date, end='\r')
    sleep(1)
```

However if you looking just to format "Mon, 25 Jul 2016 16:03:53 +0000" as you said and just remove the day consider something like this:

```
day = "Mon, 25 Jul 2016 16:03:53 +0000"
# Convert to an array
day = list(day)
# Remove first 5 characters
for i in range(5):
    day.pop(0)
day = ('').join(day)
print(day)

# You can use if statements to determine which day it is to decide how many characters to remove.
>>> "25 Jul 2016 16:03:53 +0000"
```

Comment: This is a very odd workaround. `strptime` can parse it just fine, and your entire second block of code can be done with just `day[5:]`.

Answer (score 1):

The format you need to parse is dictated by the timestamp provided by Twillo. You will likely need the following format string to properly parse the timestamp:

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(call.start_time, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"))
```

A great guide for the formatting string is http://strftime.org/.

Another good library for lazily converting dates from strings is the python-dateutil library found at https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/.